# me statement replacing member discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have a whois command that works normally but I'm trying to make it when I say .whois me it shows my info. But I Tried an if statement it didn't work

**Code:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def whois(ctx, member : discord.Member):

    with open('main code\mbot json storage\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)


    if member == "me":
        member = ctx.message.author    #I tried doing this

    prefix = prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)]

    roles = [role for role in member.roles]


    embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

    embed.set_author(name=f'User Info - {member}')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Asked by {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

    embed.add_field(name='ID:', value=member.id)
    embed.add_field(name='Guild name:', value=member.display_name)
    embed.add_field(name='Created At:', value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p "))
    embed.add_field(name='Joined At:', value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p "))
    embed.add_field(name=f'Roles ({len(roles)})', value=" ".join([role.mention for role in roles]))
    embed.add_field(name='Top role:', value=member.top_role.mention)
    embed.add_field(name="Platform", value=f"{'Mobile' if member.is_on_mobile() else 'PC'}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Admin?", value=f"{member.guild_permissions.administrator}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Bot?', value=f"{'Bot' if member.bot else 'Human'}", inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with the current code you have, you're using the `MemberConverter`, if you put `me` it's not going to work, you can simply make the member argument optional, and when it's `None` use `ctx.author` as the member argument

```py
@bot.command()
async def whois(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    # Put the rest of the code here
```

To invoke it would be simply `!whois` and it's going to give you info of yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no python expert, but I believe your command function is expecting that the `member` parameter is of type `discord.Member`. You have not stated what goes wrong when you run `.whois me`, so I will assume that the problem is caused by this type expectation.

I suggest making the parameter default to `None`, and check for that instead. This would change your self-whois command from `.whois me` to just `.whois`.
Alternatively, you could expect a string and parse the user yourself.